# RNN can't learn integral function

Tags: time-series, lstm, integral, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

For studying deep learning, RNN, LSTM and so on I tried to make RNN fit integration function. I have put random signal from 0 to 1 as input to RNN and made integral from biased by -0.5 input signal, made the limit for integral between 0:1 and put it as RNN target to learn. [Blue - random input, orange - integrated input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZPLc.png)

So I have time series with only one input (random) and one output (limited integral of input) and I want RNN to predict output by the input.
I used Pytorch and tried to use vanilla RNN, GRU cell, different sizes of hidden layers, stacking several RNN, putting dense connected layers to the RNN output, different deep in backpropagation through time (from 2 to 50 gradients rolling-back). And I can't get a good result at all! It works somehow, but I can't find a way to fit integral function precisely. Here is the best of my results:
[green - RNN output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvvIc.png). **Green line (model output) does not fit orange line in many cases - that is the problem.**

[Here is my source code in jupyter](https://github.com/Belerafon/GRU_integral/blob/master/GRU_test.ipynb). 
My questions: is it possible - to learn a saturated integral function by RNN? Where is my problem? What can I try more to achieve good quality? **Ideally I want to RNN output be equal desired output (integral function) through all time series.**

PS:
My code in raw format:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import truncnorm
import random
import math
import copy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import matplotlib.cm as cm

def generate_data(num_of_data):
    input_data=[]
    output_data=[]
    current_input_value=0
    current_output_value=0
    for i in range(num_of_data):
        if (random.random()<0.1):
            current_input_value=random.random()
#            current_output_value=0
        current_input_value=current_input_value+(random.random()-0.5)*0
        current_output_value=current_output_value+0.0*(current_input_value-current_output_value)+(current_input_value-0.5)*0.1
        if (current_output_value<0):
            current_output_value=0
        if (current_output_value>1):
            current_output_value=1

        input_data.append(current_input_value)
        output_data.append(current_output_value)
    return input_data,output_data

%matplotlib inline
matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (20, 6)

input_data,output_data=generate_data(500)
plt.plot(input_data)
plt.plot(output_data)
plt.show()


import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.autograd import Variable
from torch import optim


class RNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
        super(RNN, self).__init__()
        self.number_of_layers=1
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.gru = nn.GRU(input_size, hidden_size,self.number_of_layers)
        self.Dense1 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, hidden_size)
        self.Dense1A = nn.ReLU()
        self.Dense2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)


    def forward(self, input, hidden):
        gru_output, hidden = self.gru(input, hidden)
        Dense1Out=self.Dense1(gru_output)
        Dense1OutAct=self.Dense1A(Dense1Out)
        output=self.Dense2(Dense1OutAct)
        return output, hidden

    def initHidden(self):
        return Variable(torch.zeros(self.number_of_layers,1,self.hidden_size))



import time
import math
import operator

def timeSince(since):
    now = time.time()
    s = now - since
    m = math.floor(s / 60)
    s -= m * 60
    return '%dm %ds' % (m, s)
rnn = RNN(1, 50, 1)

n_iters = 250000
print_every = 2000
plot_every = 2000
all_losses = []
total_loss_print = 0
total_loss_plot = 0

criterion=nn.L1Loss()

print("training...\n")

start = time.time()
optimizer = optim.Adam(rnn.parameters(), lr=0.0002)
rnn_hidden = rnn.initHidden()
rnn.zero_grad()
loss = 0
#for gata_q in range(int(n_iters/500)):
#    rnn_hidden = rnn.initHidden()

input_data,output_data=generate_data(n_iters)
for data_index in range(len(input_data)):
    input_tensor=torch.zeros(1, 1, 1)
    input_tensor[0][0][0]=input_data[data_index]

    output_tensor=torch.zeros(1, 1, 1)
    output_tensor[0][0][0]=output_data[data_index]

    rnn_output, rnn_hidden = rnn(Variable(input_tensor), rnn_hidden)
    loss += criterion(rnn_output, Variable(output_tensor))


    if data_index%2==0:
        loss.backward()

        total_loss_print += loss.data[0]
        total_loss_plot += loss.data[0]
        optimizer.step()
        rnn_hidden=Variable(rnn_hidden.data)
        rnn.zero_grad()
        loss = 0

    if data_index % print_every == 0:
        print('%s (%d %d%%) tl=%.4f' % (timeSince(start), data_index, data_index / n_iters * 100,total_loss_print/print_every))
        total_loss_print = 0

    if data_index % plot_every == 0:
        all_losses.append(total_loss_plot / plot_every)
        total_loss_plot = 0



import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

plt.figure()
plt.plot(all_losses)
plt.show()

rnn_hidden = rnn.initHidden()

rnn.zero_grad()
loss = 0

rnn_output_data=[]
input_data,output_data=generate_data(1500)
for data_index in range(len(input_data)):
    input_tensor=torch.zeros(1, 1, 1)
    input_tensor[0][0][0]=input_data[data_index]
    rnn_output, rnn_hidden = rnn(Variable(input_tensor), rnn_hidden)
    rnn_output_data.append(rnn_output.data.numpy()[0][0][0])

plt.plot(input_data)#blue
plt.plot(output_data)#ogange
plt.plot(rnn_output_data)#green
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please post your code here. Tell us where's and what's the error or what is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem by myself. The problem was in some case of overfitting on latest data, as in reinforcement learning case overfitting can occur with exploiting latest strategy. As I was not using any mini-batches and applied optimiser directly after a new point of data, and as because of data points similar through 20-50 of samples, optimiser simply fitted network to only latest points forgetting of fitting previous. I solved it by collecting gradient data through time for 50 points and only after it I apply one step of optimiser. The network can learn now much better, but still not perfect.

Here is modification of code to make it work:

```
rnn_output, rnn_hidden = rnn(Variable(input_tensor), rnn_hidden)

loss += criterion(rnn_output, Variable(output_tensor))

if data_index % 2==0:
    loss.backward()
    total_loss_print += loss.data[0]
    rnn_hidden=Variable(rnn_hidden.data)
    loss = 0
   # torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm(rnn.parameters(), 0.01)
if data_index % 50==0:
    optimizer.step()
    rnn.zero_grad()
```

and new result of learning of integral:
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eoi7.png).